# Pyspark: TaskMemoryManager: Failed to allocate a page

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, out-of-memory, taskmanager

I am facing an error while running a spark job in standalone cluster mode on my server.

**Error that I'm getting is something like:**

```
WARN TaskMemoryManager: Failed to allocate a page (x bytes), try again.
```

**where x can be something like:**

[image]

**Some proposed solutions:**

[image]

**My spark job aims at:**

- Join some tables (3 to 4),
- apply some cleaning functions,
- save the result (1 df, max size 300 MB) into HDFS

**htop after running the Job:**

[image]

**My server specs:**

- RAM: 31GB
- CPU(s): 8
- Core(s) per socket: 8

**My configuration: (pseudo-code)**

```
spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled: True,
spark.driver.maxResultSize: 0,
spark.driver.memory: 15g,
spark.executor.memory: 15g,
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled: True,
spark.shuffle.service.enabled: True,
spark.network.timeout: 10000001,
spark.executor.heartbeatInterval: 10000000,
spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled: True
```

**P.S:**

- This used to work before with above details and with bigger datasets
  (around 300GB) with no problems
- Im still new to spark

**I have tried:**

- stop-all.sh (hadoop & spark)
- change the configuration `spark.executor.memory: 10g`
- add some configuration: `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold: -1`
  and `spark.sql.broadcastTimeout: 3000`

Answer (score 0):

After observing many test scenarios and trying a lot for thing,

a server restart solved the problem, I know its not the perfect solution but it does